# SourceTree Bitbucket windows password not authorized

Tags: windows, passwords, authorization, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I recently changed my windows password and pushing the changes from sourcetree to bitbucket throws unauthorized error.it was working before.  It prompts for user I'd and password and displays the error. I am able to login on the bitbucket with the same user I'd and password. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After several iterations figured it out,

Go to git cmd prompt  -> Git Push

Login / Password window pops up, cancel it and then enter the password next to the displayed bitbucket url (starting with the user id) at command line , push went thru.